# How to retrieve data from json in compoundjs controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, mongodb

hi I am new to `compound Js`.

In `compound js`, I am retrieving data from back end as data was in json format.

In my controller I wrote code to retrieve data by passing id like this-

```
action(function teamforsportsid(req, res){

return Team.find(req.params.id, function(err, team){

    if(!err) {

        return send(team[0]["_id"]);

    }else {
        return console.log(err);
    }
 });
```

});

In this team[0]["_id"] I got particular id.

In place of `team[0]["_id"]`, I used `team[0]["first_name"]` and I didnt get the name...

My json will be like this...

```
[
{
"_id": "510b51ff6ee1f5ab2800001f",

"first_name": "Pittsburgh"} ]
```

Is there any other way to retrieve data in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
action(function teamforsportsid(req, res){

return Team.find(req.params.id, req.params.first_name, function(err, team){

    if(!err) {

        return send(team[0]["_id"], team[0]["first_name"]);

    }else {
        return console.log(err);
    }
 });

});
```

Comment: hi i made mistake while write the question i is team[0]["first_name"] only

Comment: am just sending only the id not the name, and i tried  send(team[0]["_id"], team[0]["first_name"]) still am getting id only. in my json i have all data. i just have to get only id and name.

Comment: can u give me a idea how to use where condition in controller function

Comment: Use where conditions like this in a controller-  `@team = Team.where(:_id => req.params.id) if req.params.id.present?`

Comment: am asking in compound js not in ruby on rails